# $or mongoose operator works on localhost but not on production

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have just pushed my web application on my prod server and I discover a surprising issue:

```
var username = 'foo';
var User = this.db.model('User', UserSchema);
User.findOne({ $or: [ { username: username }, { email: { value: username } } ] }, 'id', function(err, Doc) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }else if (Doc) {
    console.log('OK');
  }else {
    console.log('Any result');
  }
});
```

This exact same code works on my localhost but not on my prod server (I go in the `else` condition on my production server and in the `else if (Doc)` on localhost).

I print my variable `username` just before the `findOne` call and I checked manually, this username does exist.

**If I drop the `$or` operator and only apply the condition on `username`, it works!** Which is the proof the `$or` operator is responsible of this failure.

I update my node modules the same way on my both environments (`"mongoose": ">=3.5.4"`).

My mongoDB version is the same on the both environments:

```
db version v2.0.4, pdfile version 4.5
git version: nogitversion
```

My localhost server: `ubuntu`.
My prod server: `debian`.

How could we explain that?

Comment: What version of MongoDB is on your production server?

Comment: The same on the both: `db version v2.0.4, pdfile version 4.5 git version: nogitversion
`

Comment: What's going on with the `'id' function...` part on the second line?  Typo?

Comment: Yes sorry the ',' was forgotten here but not in my original code.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded mongodb to the `v2.2.3` on my prod server and it works...